# How to use while loop in F# Async expression?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How would I go about writing the following in F#?

```cs
var reader = await someDatabaseCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
  var foo = reader.GetDouble(1);
  // ... 
}
```

I'm very new to F# so this is the best I can come up with

```ml
task { 
  let! reader = someDatabaseCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync ()
  let! tmp1 = reader.ReadAsync ()
  let mutable hasNext = tmp1
  while hasNext do
    // ...
    let! tmp2 = reader.ReadAsync ()
    hasNext <- tmp2
}
```

I know it's a C# library so it's not going to be perfect, but I'd like to avoid needing to store the result of `ReadAsync` in a variable, let alone have two temporaries. I don't know of a way to get the "result" of a `Task` without binding it to a name. Perhaps a recursive solution would work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This library works very nicely with C#, because you can use `await` in the condition of the loop. I think that using recursive computation expression in F# is a bit nicer than the imperative solution (I do not think you can simplify that), but it is about the same length:

```
task {
  let! reader = someDatabaseCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync ()
  let rec loop () = task { 
    let! hasNext = reader.ReadAsync ()
    if hasNext then
      // ..
      return! loop () }
  return! loop ()
}
```

A more elaborate solution would be to use F# asynchronous sequences (from the [FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq library](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/)). I think this only works for `async` (and so you'd have to use that instead of `task`), but it makes the code nicer. You can define a function that runs a command and returns an asynchronous sequence of results (for simplicity, I just return the `reader`, which is a bit dirty, but works):

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq"
#r "nuget: System.Data.SqlClient"
open FSharp.Control

let runCommand (cmd:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand) = asyncSeq { 
  let! reader = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
  let rec loop () = asyncSeq { 
    let! hasNext = reader.ReadAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
    if hasNext then
      yield reader
      yield! loop () }
  yield! loop () }
```

Given this, you can very nicely iterate over the results using plain `for` loop inside `async` (using an overload added by the AsyncSeq library):

```
async { 
  for reader in runCommand someDatabaseCommand do
    let foo = reader.GetDouble(1) 
    () }
```

Comment: Worth noting is that task isn’t tail recursive so it can blow up quickly on longer sequences

Comment: @user1981 Thanks for pointing this out! In that case, it may make sense to switch to `async` where this is not a problem

Comment: You could also use F#+ `SeqT` https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus//type-seqt.html so you don't have to convert back and forth from `Async`. Then just replace in the above code `Async.AwaitTask` with `SeqT.lift` and `asyncSeq` with `monad.plus`.

Comment: @user1981 If I convert tasks to `async` with `Async.AwaitTask` does it become tail recursive then?

Comment: @Adam - Yes, I believe so.